# IF statement in Google Sheets from converted xls

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting

I have transferred these xls into G SHeets but the IFs don't work in Cells U9 onwards. I know the tick boxes don't work because of no WIngdings in Google however if we enter R for a student in cells E9, F9, G9, etc, eventually U9 should say Pass. More R's along the row means U9 should say Merit etc

https://drive.google.com/file/d/117n553pXdiaC7MEOZ3xGphmrXJn50L_s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i do, apologies!  here is the link, i hope you can help
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HnfyIJPo5JSbfQ4zh5neAyfltOWaJKhx/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

font was set to white, formula is fine

```
=IF(COUNTIF($E9:$T9, "R")=16, "Distinction",
 IF(COUNTIF($E9:$P9, "R")=12, "Merit",
 IF(COUNTIF($E9:$K9, "R")=7, "Pass", 
 IF(SUM(COUNTIF($E9:$K9, "R"), COUNTIF($E9:$K9, "8"))=7, "Pass Referral", 
 IF(SUM(COUNTIF($E9:$K9, "R"), COUNTIF($E9:$K9, "T"), COUNTIF($E9:$K9, "8"))=7, "Unsafe", "z")))))
```

[image: 0]

see **[spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iXYYe2g9P5X1vMtm30c4fMSyAP1R5hm5aM1z2NwGSEM/edit#gid=951895571)**